# DLL file name for the SAS Add-In reference in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sas

What is the correct dll file name to load as reference in Excel VBA 2010, that correspond to SAS Add-in 7.1. I want to use VBA in the place to use the Tools menu.

I have tried :

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAS\SASHome\x86\SASAddinforMicrosoftOffice\7.1\SAS.OfficeAddin.dll"
```

and

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAS\SASHome\x86\SASAddinforMicrosoftOffice\7.1\office.dll"
```

They didn't work.

Thank you

Comment: *"They didn't work."* is no usefull description of your error. Please be more specific.

Comment: I have The error 48 : Error to load the DLL.

Comment: This error has the following causes and solutions: [Error in loading DLL (Error 48)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/error-in-loading-dll-error-48)

Comment: Also make sure that if using Excel 64bit that that dll must support 64bit too. Does it work to load the dll from this location manually (not by clicking something that is already in the list) using the menu?

Comment: Yes, I have 64bit system. Do you know how to verify if the DLL support 64bit? It is not apparent in the properties of the DLL.

Comment: Try to add it manually or read in the documentation of that add-in.

Comment: Manually, it is working perfectly!!! I have tried it.

Comment: Did you load it manually from exactly this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\SAS\SASHome\x86\SASAddinforMicrosoftOffice\7.1\office.dll`? Because since it resides in the `x86` folder I assume that this is the 32 bit version of the add-in. Check if there is `x64` folder too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct DLL file for Excel SAS Add-In for SAS 7.1 is "SAS.OfficeAddin.tlb".

it is in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAS\SASHome\x86\SASAddinforMicrosoftOffice\7.1\".

To add this reference by using VBA :

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAS\SASHome\x86\SASAddinforMicrosoftOffice\7.1\SAS.OfficeAddin.tlb"
```